# Creating a list of java.sql.date in Scala from a date range

Tags: java, scala, date, data-structures

I have 2 date values (`startDate` and `endDate`), which are both objects of `java.sql.date` class.

How do I create a list that contains dates of every date between (and including) these dates?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to convert the dates to `java.time.LocalDate` so that you can use the `datesUntil()` method.

```
import scala.jdk.StreamConverters.StreamHasToScala

val dates: List[java.sql.Date] =
  startDate.toLocalDate()
           .datesUntil(endDate.toLocalDate().plusDays(1))
           .toScala(List)  //from Java Stream to Scala List
           .map(java.sql.Date.valueOf)
```

Better still is to drop `java.sql.Date` altogether and just stick with `java.time.LocalDate`.